# 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1... Print 2016

Tags: number, restricted-source, code-golf, expression-building

As a spin-off to [my challenge over at Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/25039/10-9-8-7-6-5-4-3-2-1-2016), your goal is to output `2016`.

Rules:

- You must include the numbers `10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1` in that order. They can be used as individual integers or concatenated together (like `1098`), but the `10` may not be separated into `1` and `0` - no character(s) may be present between the digits. Note that, in some languages, `10` may not actually represent the integer literal `10`, which is acceptable.
- Your code must not contain any other numbers or pre-defined number variables or constants (so `T` in Pyth is not allowed, since it is a numeric constant).
- You must **calculate** `2016` using numerics. Simply outputting `2016` without performing any operations on the required numbers (for example, by decoding an encoded string consisting of only alphabetic characters) is not allowed. Outputting `2016` in pieces (such as `20`, then `16`) is also not allowed; you must have a single output consisting of the numeric value `2016`.
- The valid answer with the fewest bytes wins.

Comment: @nicael I'm pretty sure solving the puzzle has been done. We've had several of these "insert operators to solve an equation" challenges, but they are exceptional hard to search for.

Comment: The previous revision (2) was more interesting actually. The new is just printing the string, the calculation was already made in your puzzling question...

Comment: Just a few questions based on what I can see on the current question: 1) Can we calculate `20` and `16` and print them one after the other or does the calculated number need to be 2016 before printing? 2) Are functions allowed? 3) Is concatenation of digits allowed? e.g. `1098` (I'm assuming yes by previous comments, but just to confirm) 4) Does "calculate 2016 using integers" mean that we can never have floats anywhere in an intermediate step? e.g. can I square root a number and round down?

Comment: 5) What happens if I have a language where "10" is not treated as the number ten, but rather a one followed by a zero and there was no way around it? Is such a language disqualified? (example language: Befunge) 6) Can we use a predefined number variable *in place of* 10, e.g. `T987654321`?

Comment: @Sp3000 1 No. 2 No. 3 Yes. 4 Floats are OK as long as you don't break any other rules. 5 `10` must be included so you would need to handle that somehow. 6 As long as `10` appears before `T`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Just regarding 5 and 6, does "10" must be included mean the character 1 then the character 0, or something that represents the number ten? I think that's what I was confused about.

Comment: @Sp3000 `1` then `0` immediately after. Imagine if I use Find on your code and search for `10`. If it doesn't exist, it's not a valid entry.

Comment: k, that makes sense. Sorry for the question barrage!

Comment: Clarification about Pyth: `T` is a variable, not a constant.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has unobservable requirements of "using arithmetic" and "not allowing numeric constants".

Answer (score 22):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>17</s> <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```
109876:54+3_21
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=MTA5ODc2OjU0KzNfMjE&input=)

#### How it works

```
109876:54+3_21

109876            Initialize the left argument as 109876.
      :54         Perform integer division by 54, yielding 2034.
         +3       Add 3, yielding 2037.
           _21    Subtract 21, yielding 2016.
```

Answer (score 8):

## Hexagony, 61 bytes

Not gonna win, but I just wanted to do a challenge in Hexagony.

This uses a different method than other answers (much worse). It takes some factors of 2016 (2,3,6,7,8) and multiplies them all together.

Minified:

```
\109.8/7}_=\"6<}{>...$_5_4/*!@...../}3.."2\/="*=}<*...$1>"*"/
```

Unminified:

```
    \ 1 0 9 .
   8 / 7 } _ =
  \ " 6 < } { >
 . . . $ _ 5 _ 4
/ * ! @ . . . . .
 / } 3 . . " 2 \
  / = " * = } <
   * . . . $ 1
    > " * " /
```

Explanation coming soon;

Comment: "_Explanation coming soon;_" I think we have a different understanding of 'soon'. ;P

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Whoops, I completely forgot about this. ... And now I don't understand how it works anymore. Great.

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, 16 bytes

```
+/109876 54-3 21
```

Does integer division, then adds (3-21).

Try it [here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2B%2F109876+54-3+21&debug=0).

Answer (score 4):

### TI-BASIC, <s>17</s> 15 bytes

```
int(109876/54-√(321
```

This uses @nicael's method.

17 bytes:

```
10+9*8-7+654*3-21
```

[This solution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/25050/12917) from Puzzling can be directly translated into TI-BASIC.

Comment: Also valid in Japt, and probably some others.

Comment: Also works in PowerShell, and Mathematica (Wolfram), and I would imagine many, many others. And probably works in dozens more with trivial modifications.

Comment: A lovely polyglot solution

Comment: If you want to take the other languages, I'll delete my community wiki one.

Answer (score 3):

## Japt, <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
Â(109876/54-321q
```

<s>I hate this 17. Probably will find another solution.</s> YAYZ.

Explanation:

- `321q` is a square root of 321.
- `~~` floors the number.

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=wigxMDk4NzYvNTQtMzIxcQ==&input=)

Comment: `Â` == `~~` :-)

Comment: `109876/54-321¬f` is 15 :-D

Comment: @Eth but f doesn't work, no?

Comment: It should be fixed. But the interpreter is down for maintenance right now, I'll get it back up momentarily.

Comment: `109876/54-321q)f` now works. The other suggestion doesn't.

Comment: @Eth your first suggestion does work and provide the same nice 16 bytes, not going to upgrade. (Also because it'll render my answer non-competing)

Comment: Yep, just letting you know that it works again.

Answer (score 3):

## Matlab / Octave, 23 bytes

```
(10-9+8-7)^(6-5+4)*3*21
```

[Try it online](http://ideone.com/cLWq29)

Answer (score 3):

## bc, 14

```
109876/54+3-21
```

Nothing exciting here - borrows from other answers.

Comment: The dc equivalent `109876 54/3+21-p` scores 16, but doesn't warrant an answer of its own.

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 31 bytes

```
[10,9*8*7+const 6 5..]!!4+3*2*1
```

Not the shortest, `10+9*8-7+654*3-21` like seen in other answers works in Haskell too, but something different.

This builds a list starting with `10` and `9*8*7+6 = 510`, so the offset is `500` for the following elements. The whole list is `[10,510,1010,1510,2010,2510 ...]`. We pick the `4th` element (index 0-based), i.e. `2010` and add `3*2*1 = 6`. Voilà.

I use `const 6 5 = 6` to get rid of the `5` which is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 20 bytes

```
print 109876/54+3-21
```

Again, that same boring `2016.(740)`. Makes use of the fact that if you don't have a decimal number in your expression it returns an integer.

Answer (score 1):

## Polyglot, 17 Bytes

```
10+9*8-7+654*3-21
```

This code, first used in [Thomas Kwa's TI-BASIC answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68682/44713), also works in:

- AppleScript (full program)
- bc (full program)
- Math++ (expression or full program)
- Mathematica (function, therefore not valid)
- Powershell (full program)
- Japt (full program)
- <s>JavaScript (console input, therefore not valid)</s> Needs second verification
- <s>Perl 5 (function, therefore not valid).</s> Needs second verification
- Haskell (function, therefore not valid)
- Python REPL (expression, so REPL environment is needed to get the output)

Comment: And, what's the point?

Comment: @nicael I'm ---going--- am planning (unless Thomas Kwa wishes to add the other answers to his as well) to add all of the answers that involve this answer (except TI-BASIC) that I can find. Marked as Community so that others can contribute.

Comment: This is not a valid answer as it does not constitute a full program or function (AFAIK) in *any* of the specified languages.

Comment: @AlexA. It works fine [here](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=MTArOSo4LTcrNjU0KjMtMjE=&input=) (Japt) as a full program.

Comment: @ThomasKwa So it's valid in 1 out of 6 of the listed languages.

Comment: @AlexA. This is a full program in AppleScript. Running this through AppleScript's Script Editor _or_ through osascript outputs the value.

Comment: Why does this have downvotes?

Comment: Why the "function, therefore not valid" remarks? Functions are allowed by default.

Comment: I don't know about the other languages, but `10+9*8-7+654*3-21` is neither a JavaScript nor a Perl function.

Comment: @nimi The question says "print", which implies a program.

Comment: The Python REPL doesn't count as its own language

Comment: @AlexA. See [relevant meta discussion](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7844/45941)

Comment: @FlagAsSpam: I don't see that "print" implies "program". Do we have the distinction between "print" and "output"? I can't remember, but may I err here. Default output methods for functions are their return value. Besides that, we have a [meta topic](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/902/is-an-answer-valid-if-it-works-only-at-the-interactive-prompt/914#914) that allows answers that work in repl environments, so if the repl prints for you, you're fine.

Comment: @nimi Just clarified with the OP: functions are now explicitly disallowed (see main post comments)

Comment: @Sp3000: Oh these invalidating rule changes ...

Answer (score 1):

## [Math++](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Math%2B%2B), 17 bytes

```
_(109876/54)+3-21
```

Actually, this prints `2016.0`. But there's really no way to print the exact string `2016` in this language.

The 17-byte TI-BASIC solution would also work here.

Answer (score 1):

## [BotEngine](https://github.com/SuperJedi224/Bot-Engine), <s>42</s> <s>39</s> <s>36</s> 13x2=26

```
v109876543210
>ee   e@  eRP
```

Answer (score 1):

## ><> (fish), 18 bytes

```
10987**r65r4*n;321
```

explaination:

multiplies 9 8 and 7 together to get 504, reverses the stack and reverses it again right before the 4 is added, then multiplies 504 and 4 to get 2016. Then prints the number and ends the program before the last 3 numbers (i could do it after too with no difference, if that matters rules-wise).

Answer (score 1):

## 2, 15 chars / 17 bytes

```
109876/54+3-21⍜
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter2.html?eval=false&input=&output=&code=109876%2F54%2B3-21%E2%8D%9C)</kbd>

Translates to `round(109876/54+3-21)`.

*Thanks to @Dennis for saving 2 bytes!*

Answer (score 1):

## Java 7, 31 bytes

```
int c(){return 109876/54+3-21;}
```

Boring port from other answers, of which I believe [*@Dennis*' Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68687/52210) was the first.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 27 bytes

```
<?=~~(109876/54+3-21);
```

(22 bytes) was too boring,

so I used 10 to 9 as separate numbers:

```
<?=10*(9-8+7-6),5+4-3+2<<1;
```

other solutions, mostly with small cheats:

```
30: <?=10**(9+8-7-6)/5+4*3+(2<<1);
30: <?=10*trim(9*8,7),6+5+4+3-2*1;
29: <?=10*trim(9*8,76),5*4-3-2+1;
31: <?=10*trim(9*8,765),4+(3*2<<1);
31: <?=10*trim(9*8,765),4*3+(2<<1);
32: <?=ceil(1098*76/54)+321+ord(~j);
33: <?=(10<<9)/876*543/M_PI*2-M_E&~1;
```

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://esolangs.org/wiki/CJam), 15 bytes

```
109876 54/3+21-
```

Another port from Dennis' answer that I suspect works for many stack-based languages except 05AB1E, which seems to be the only stack-based answer besides Forth, which needs several more bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## [Milky Way 1.6.5](https://github.com/zachgates7/Milky-Way), <s>28</s> 25 bytes

```
10+9*(8)7;^*6*5/4*3/2*A!1
```

---

#### Explanation

```
10+9*                      ` perform 10*9 (leaves 90 at TOS)
     (8)7;^*               ` get rid of 8 and multiply the TOS by 7
            6*5/4*3/2*A    ` perform TOS*6/5*4/3*2 (leaves 2016 at TOS)
                       !   ` output the TOS
                        1  ` push 1 to the stack
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 15 bytes

```
109876 54÷3+21-
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=MTA5ODc2IDU0w7czKzIxLQ&input=)

Port of Dennis' answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Forth, 22 bytes

Same calculation seen in other answers.

```
109876 54 / 3 + 21 - .
```

[**Try it online**](https://repl.it/ElA3)

Answer (score 0):

## C 37 bytes

```
main(){printf("%d",109876/54+3-21);}
```

Same theme as many present.

Answer (score 0):

## VBA, 15 bytes

```
?109876\54+3-21
```

(calculation unashamedly stolen from [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68687/5011))

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 21 bytes

```js
f=

_=>~~(109876/54+3-21)

console.log(f())
```

If the "countdown" went to 0, it could be done in 19 bytes.

```js
f=
_=>109876/54+3-21|0
console.log(f())
```

And, seeing as it's 2017 now, that can also be done in 21 bytes:

```js
f=
_=>-~(109876/54+3-21)
console.log(f());
```